# Is there a way to turn off the sidebar auto "sideways-scroll" for long directory names

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, scrolling

When any long directory name comes into view in the sidebar, Windows explorer scrolls the entire list sideways which loses (typically) the directory I'm actually trying to find. Is there a way to turn off this incredibly annoying behaviour? I'm pretty good at doing my own scrolling, thank you very much.

Comment: I know the behavior you refer to, but being on Windows 10 I can't replicate it to check for a disable option.

Comment: Might also be related to https://superuser.com/questions/206525/can-i-enable-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-the-navigation-panel-of-windows-7-explo

Comment: Thanks for links; TBH, this behaviour is exhibited in several different places. I've changed to Explorer++ rather than Windows Explorer, but Explorer++ side panel auto-scrolls in the same way and has a horizontal scroll bar below; TortoiseSVN 1.8.11.26392(64bit) does the same and also has a horizontal scroll bar. Seems like it might be part of a WinUI library.